# What can NLI do for a chatbot?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp

Natural Language Inference(NLI) is the task of predicting the labels(entailment, contradiction, and neutral,) for sentence pairs.

People invent a lot of deep model to solve this problem.

But I can not think of some application or scenario for this kind of deep model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this paper: Dialogue Natural Language Inference.

Here is the link: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P19-1363

Answer (score 0):

Well, any application which requires some level of semantic understanding could potentially benefit from this, obviously. This includes most major applications such as machine translation and question answering. Traditional approaches can give decent results in terms of grammatical structure or topic similarity, but they are prone to serious counter-sense errors because they lack any form of semantic logic.